# how to create a custom field in nuch search engine?

Tags: nutch

i want to create a custom field in nutch search engine?
what are the steps i will follow?

Answer (score 1):

I would think your best option is to develop a Nutch Plugin which handles the logic for adding that field on a per crawled page basis.

Please see the [Writing Plugin Example](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/WritingPluginExample) wiki article on the Nutch site.